# How do you href a .ejs file in HTML

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to build a login system with Nodejs and express. I have a login page with the login forms using ejs.

In my `index.html` file there's a button that's supposed to direct the user to that login page:

```html
<button id="loginBtn">
<a href="views/login.ejs"><LI> LOGIN </LI></a>
</button>
```

but it prints the ejs code of the login page instead of displaying the actual page. Anyone know what I'm doing worng?

Comment: is this Node.JS ?

Comment: i’m not familiar with ejs specifically, but generally with template languages you’d need an endpoint on your webapp that renders the template to html. you wouldn’t link to the template directly. if you’re using express you’d [configure ejs as the template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and set up a route to use a particular template.

Comment: There is a possibility that you can also render dynamically client side, but I wanted to know how and where you started for a server and which type of programming you do

Comment: Yes, whenever I run the login system individually on a localhost using app.listen(), my login.ejs works fine, but now i'm trying to access it from my index.html file but I cant

Comment: very good, so you confirmed that you are actually using EJS with ExpressJS with Node.JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a view, you only specify an endpoint in expressjs and call only that end point

You should not try to call the `.ejs` file location

Example:  in this code `login.ejs` will automatically render behind the scene, the server library will do it, `res.render('login')` will automatically call `login.ejs`

```
 router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login');
 });
```

You hyperlink should be calling the router mapping endpoint alone

```
 <a href="/home"><li> LOGIN </li></a>
```

once you decided using EJS, for UI designing purpose, if the UI designing part alone is given to you, then you can do a dummy code to render one EJS with fixed data, you don't have to run the entire website with DB

For example: there a data which is assumed which will render a EJS, to render with dummy data you can do this

Get the data from the developer who is doing his part and do this code

```
 router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = {"name": "Emmanuel"}
    res.render('login', data);
 });
```

as you can see the data is directly coded `temporary`

Comment: do I have to run my entire web app on a localhost for nodejs to work properly? Because right now the already built site is running locally from its file directory

Comment: given the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old question but I found OPs post when searching for a solution of my own for a similar problem.

```js
  // this link should take me to the 'new post' page which is rendered only from an ejs template (no HTML) and has a matching endpoint on my express router obj as 'new'
  <a href="new" class="new-post-link">new post</a>

  // clicking this link would move the user to the /new endpoint and would render the 'new post' page upon clicking the link
  <a href="new" class="new-post-link">new post</a>

  // for OP's specific problem:

  // original
  <button id="loginBtn">
    <a href="views/login.ejs"><LI> LOGIN </LI></a>
  </button>
  
  // solution
  <button id="loginBtn">
    <a href="login"><LI> LOGIN </LI></a>
  </button>
```

I hope it helps someone.